# Parameter Error when trying to write into Access Database

Tags: asp-classic

I received the following error on an application which I'm using Classic ASP as 
the programming language, and Access Database (accdb)

> ADODB.Parameter error '800a0d5d'
>   Application uses a value of the wrong type for the current operation.

I'm using `memo` as the data type in Access Database. The content which I'm trying to write into the database is retrieved from a Text Area, and contains HTML Scripts.

Here's the parameter:

```
objCommand.Parameters(1).value = content
```

Anyone has any suggestions on what I should do?

Comment: How are you creating the parameter ?

Comment: What driver are you using to connect to the database?

Comment: Please add your code that affects your content variable and creates the command and parameter, it will help a lot to see what is going wrong.

Answer (score -1):

Use `objCommand.Parameters(1)` for to force convert to string